# Built PDF on Elsevier platform has unexpected line numbers, which are not requested in LaTeX source code

Tags: linenumber

I am submitting my manuscript on Elsevier platform (journal: **Engineering Structures**) using their default template bundle, which includes `cas-dc-template.tex`, `cas-common.sty`, and `cas-sc.cls`. I find that the built PDF online has unexpected line numbers (see the attached figure below), which were not requested in my LaTeX codes and didn't appear in the locally compiled PDF file. These strange line numbers are similar to the ones output by package `lineno`, while the font is like `monospaced` and they restart from each page. The figure below presents the local part of the output PDF.

[image: The unexpected line numbers compiled by Elsevier. These problematic numbers re-start from each page]

The below shows my header LaTeX codes to use packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,hidelinks]{cas-sc}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}
```

I didn't encounter this problem when I was submiting to another elsevier journal **Soil Dynamic and Earthquake Engineering** using the same main codes. Is there any solution to these unexpected line numbers? And what could be the possible reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: probably they add them for the review in their online system (it is a preprint after all).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks Ulrike. I also had this idea before, while these line numbers restarted from every new page. So, I guess there may be something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

After confirming with my colleagues who have submitted papers to Elsevier's journals before, this problem that I encountered possibly is just a default system operation to facilate the review process, as Ulrike inferred.